# Автоматическое задание высоты дива

Tags: css3, html

Всем здрасте)
Есть код:

```
<div id="main" style="resize:both; overflow:auto; background-color: green">
  <div id="title">Заголовок</div>
  <div id="text">Текст</div>
</div>
```

Элемент с id title занимает только верхнюю часть(примерно 15px) элемента с id main. Всё остальное свободное место должен занимать элемент с id title.
Как видно из стиля дива с id main, пользователь может самостоятельно изменять его размер.
Проблема в том, что при изменении высоты main, высота text не изменяется. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: javascript, по-моему больше никак

Comment: А мне в этом вопросе нравится stylesheet injection :-) По хорошему, всей этой типографически навязчивой строке надо бы сделать display:none

Comment: sercxjo, ну с помощью js конечно можно, но как-то не хочется его везде писать, особенно если можно обойтись без него.

Comment: karmadro4, ээмм.. что?)) Что за инъекции?)

Comment: Решил попробовать с помощью js. Вешаю обработчик onresize="alert('text');"  но на изменения размеров элемента он не реагирует. Почему?

Comment: @LightShock, внимательно осмотрите эту страницу :-)

Comment: @karmadro4, что именно смотреть? Если вы можете помочь, то выражайтесь чётче, пожалуйста.

Comment: 5 раз перечитал...

Элемент с **id title** занимает только верхнюю часть(примерно 15px) элемента с id main. Всё остальное свободное место должен занимать элемент с **id title**

это как ?

Comment: @shurik, у ТС явно очепятка. Он имел в виду, что остально пространство должен занимать div с id="text"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как то [так](http://jsfiddle.net/Z5tck/) ?

Comment: Спасибо) То, что нужно)
З.Ы. прошу прощения, как заметил Deonis, у меня опечатка в формулировке вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

А не проще будет ресайзить сам блок `<div id="text">Текст</div>`

Comment: Я сначала так и делал, но при изменении размера text размеры main не корректно изменяются.